# React Native Navigation Wrong Credentials Rerender Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have this main stack navigator:

```
     {loading ? (
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="LoadingScreen"
          component={LoadingScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      ) : isSignedIn == false ? (
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="AuthStackScreen"
          component={AuthStackScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      ) : (
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="MainTabs"
          component={BottomTabNavigator}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      )}
```

The variables come from redux here.

Here is the submithandler function in my Login screen component.

```
  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!email) {
      alert('Please fill in the email');
      setEmailMessage('Please enter a valid email address');
      return;
    }
    if (!password) {
      alert('Please fill in the password');
      setPasswordMessage('Please enter a password');
      return;
    }

    if (error) {
      setMessage(
        'The email or password you entered is incorrect. Please check and try again.',
      );
      alert(`there is an error for email or password`);
    }
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };
```

The problem is that if the user enters his or her credentials wrong, the the mainstacknavigator understandably re-renders and sends the user to the entry screen. So, although I set them correctly, I cannot show the user the wrong password or email error.

Comment: Re-render shouldn't navigate user to other screen. Isn't your `navigation.replace("SignupScreen")` doing it?

Comment: No that is something I had added to debug to see if I can make it direct to some other page. It still directs to AuthScreen. Edited the above for clarity